# Can we handle multipart request with jar file in karate API automation tool?

Tags: karate

I am trying to use jar file as multiform data in karate and the following is my sample request

```
 Given path 'myBaseurl/v2/Import'
            And multipart file myFile = {read: 'path/to/my/jar/myJar.jar', filename: 'myJar.jar', contentType: 'multipart/form-data'}
            And header Authorization = basicAuthToken
            And method post
            Then status 200
```

Does karate support jar as multiform data?

below is the cURL

```
curl -X POST \
  https:<URL>/v2/Import \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <XXX>' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 4526292' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=<XXX>; AWSALB=<XXX>' \
  -H 'Host: <HOST>' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: <XXX>,<XXX>' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YxxxxrZu0gW' \
  -F '=@/<C:\absolute path to nm>.jar'
```

Comment: Your example doesn't look correct. Your missing a url, but it looks like from your path parameter that your base url goes into the path definition. 
Furthermore, your curl is from postman, not soap-ui.

And it would be great if you could provide some log messages. I would guess, that the content header isn't correct, because of the error message "improper json". 
What karate version are you using?

With a test on my side, I could send a multi form part data file successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Karate supports any type of (binary) file as multiform data.

Comment: when I try to hit the url. I am getting the following error:"Improper JSON request received. Unable to map request." but when I try with soup UI, the request got successful. Do I need to convert the jar to binary or any other. Can you please help me on this

Comment: @chetanrajiv you must have missed some header or your request is wrong. open a new (more clear) question, see if you can paste a cURL command that works, and we can suggest. "soup UI" should be able to export a cURL command. otherwise I have no other suggestion except for follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hey @Peter, i have added cURL to the above question. does that show me some way?

Comment: @chetanrajiv this is too complex for me to figure. I suggest you work with the team that owns the server side. or hope someone else here can help you